# What is the mystery number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you begin with a one digit integer, multiply by 3,

add 8, divide by 2 and subtract 6, you will get the

integer back.

What is the number?

Comment: $(3x+8)/2 - 6 = x$, $x=...?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{3x+8}{2} - 6 = x$

$3x + 8 = 2x + 12$

$x = 4$